# Write a example for invariant in struct

Tags: rust

After read this document(https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html) in Rust, I'm curious about how to write an example about struct variance taking effect.

```
struct MyType<'b> {
        z: UnsafeCell<&'b f64>,
    }

    fn check(my_type: MyType<'static>) {}

    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        {
            let f = &1f64;
            let unsafe_cell = UnsafeCell::new(f);
            // this my_type 's lifetime scope is not 'static
            let my_type = MyType { z: unsafe_cell };
            // why this check method pass through compilation??
            check(my_type);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `&1f64` is `&'static` - "static promotion" is, AFAIK, the relevant search term. So your `MyType` value is also `'static`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the lifetime of `&1f64` **is** static. This is because `1` is just a constant stored in the executable, so you can safely take a shared reference to it and expect it to last until the end of the program.

If you change the declaration of `f` to something like:

```
let v = 1f64;
let f = &v;
```

...build will fail with the expected "borrowed value does not live long enough".

Comment: Thanks very much! I write another example https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6c1f72af49526390eec9a9d8616cdd34, can you tell me why this code can pass the compilation?

Comment: @Frio Likely because `my_type` outlives `check_type` - but perhaps you should ask a separate question.